# Woocommerce rest API - 'Error: Invalid signature - provided signature does not match

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to download order details from a woocommerce API for easy display and update purpose.
I tested the entire setup locally with two separate web addresses. One for test woocommerce install [copy from production site] and one for order display webpage.

Everything works fine locally. But when I connect the order display to production. It downloads all orders and display according to my design, But when I try to update an order it throws an exception.

After googling for a while found that this could be caused by timezone differences, checked time on both server and my pc it was spot on.

> Anyway I changed
>
> > php timezone to correct one on both server and pc php.ini and restarted httpd
> >
> > changed server linux timezone and rebooted the server.

Still, I get following only in production[hosted in AWS]. In no expert on php, but got some programming knowledge. Anyone who can point me to correct direction?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
'Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException' with message 'Error:     
Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.     
[woocommerce_rest_authentication_error]' in     
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderdash\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php:348 Stack trace: #0     
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderdash\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php(378): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->lookForErrors(Object(stdClass)) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderdash\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php(414): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse() #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderdash\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\Client.php(69): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('orders/544', 'PUT', Array) #3 
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderdash\index.php(149): Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->put('orders/544', Array) #4 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\orderdash\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php on line 348
```

Connection

```
$woocommerce = new Client('http://example.com/',
'ck_321cad474478e1275',
'cs_76f8566e67cd7aa31',
['wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v1']);
```

Download orders

```
$data = ['status' => 'processing'];
$order_details = $woocommerce->get('orders',$data);
```

update data [use a button submit]

```
$update_order_id = $_POST['orderid'];
$st = ['status' => 'completed'];
$woocommerce->put('orders/'. $update_order_id, $st);
```

Comment: No one with a clue?

Comment: Hi, it happened to me as well suddenly after update to 3.4.3 perhaps it's related. Did you manage to find out anything about it?

Comment: No, I'm running WP4.9.4 and WC3.2.6 still nothing. but then when I test code against local dev running on xamp it works fine. So I uploaded the script to prod for testing the same error. Im confused now.

Comment: I've been reading about it and it turns out that the most common reason you see this is a difference in php date_default_timezone between the two systems. `https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET/issues/59`

Comment: Yep true, there was a lot of chatter about that and I corrected that too. linux and php setting in server. Also client php setting calling the API. Did you found a solution or did the timezone thing fixed it.

Comment: Also I have read that some plugins can cause API issues. But in my case all the plugins are same in local copy and production.

Comment: I personally gave up and switched to https authentication instead of oauth for my needs which worked without issues as I didn't have access to the woocommerce end to debug it. Sorry I couldn't be of any help in this case

Comment: I can confirm that WPML can cause this issue. (It at least does so in the local, but not remote environment)